# Automatic Update of datetime on Table Update :MS SQL08

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to insert the current datetime whenever a new row is inserted or updated.
The getdate() gives the datetime whenever a row is inserted. But it doesn’t update itself at the time of row update.
Is there any way to do this?

**Edit:** I don't want to use Triggers.

[image: Field Structure]

Comment: You might want to consider [`SYSDATETIME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx) instead of `getdate()` - it will use more of the available precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stored procedure may help you then, but then an ad-hoc update operation will lead to inconsistent data.

Comment: Yes, triggers are pretty much the only way you can guarantee this kind of functionality. Unless someone drops, disables, or alters the trigger, of course.

Comment: I don't want to use triggers. Is there any other options?

Answer (score 6):

This is the Trigger you need for update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update ON TABLE1 
FOR UPDATE
 AS  

BEGIN   

SET NOCOUNT ON  

    UPDATE  TABLE1  
   SET   UpdatedOn = GETDATE()   
      FROM    TABLE1 A          
   INNER JOIN Inserted INS ON (A.Id = INS.Id) 

     SET NOCOUNT OFF

  END
```

Comment: The query wouldn't run for me as 'Update' is a keyword. Changed it to 'UpdateTrigger' and it all worked perfectly. Thanks.